# Print values horizontally in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel sheet with data formatted as below

```
  A        B
1 KEY      VALUE
2 Apple    Golden
3 Orange   Navel
4 Banana   Yellow
5 Apple    Granny Smith
6 Orange   Blood
```

What I want to do is take the unique keys, but print their corresponding values horizontally next to them.  I already have a sheet that looks like this:

```
  A        B
1 KEY      VALUE
2 Apple    Golden
3 Orange   Navel
4 Banana   Yellow
```

But what I would like is this:

```
  A        B        C
1 KEY      VALUE1   VALUE2
2 Apple    Golden   Granny Smith
3 Orange   Navel    Blood
4 Banana   Yellow
```

My formula right now is `{=INDEX('$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(<unique key>,$A$2:$A$6,0))}` where "unique key" is the cell reference in the second sheet.  This formula successfully prints the first value for each key, but I would like for the other matches to populate down the row.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work if you setup formulas in columns to handle as many 'VALUE' instances as you think you'll find. So you'll need to setup formulas in the 'VALUE columns.

Use an array formula that includes a conditional **IF**() to check your key value, then the **SMALL**() function to return the n'th row matching that value. This tells you that for the key APPLE, the value occurs in rows 1 and 5 of your table. Then use the **INDEX**() to fetch the VALUE from those rows.

This page has details with an example. Your example is going to run horizontally instead of vertically, but otherwise it's an identical problem.
http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list#sthash.7XGIoc9N.dpbs

The only adjustment I'll  recommend is at the end, when you add the **IF**(**ISERROR**()... etc., the shorter/easier way to do this is to use the **IFERROR**() function, so this way you don't have to repeat your long formula.

For example, if I had your table (excluding col. headers) in A13:B17, then my result table started with the KEY values in E13:E15, so 'Apple' in E13, then the first formula in F13 (to find the VALUE for the first occurrence of 'Apple') would be (*array* formula, so **Ctrl**-**Shft**-**Enter**):

> {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$13:$B$17,SMALL(IF($A$13:$A$17=$E13,ROW($A$13:$A$17)),ROW(1:1))-12,2),"")}

And the result would be "Golden".

Then in G13, it would be the same except ROW(2:2). H13 would use ROW(3:3). And so on for as many columns as needed to cover maximum anticipated VALUE's for any KEY.

Then rows below would be the same, except for the first IF() conditional that checks for the KEY value.